# OnePage Checkout - Hide Payment method depending on Shipping Method

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, payment-methods

I'm using CE 1.9.0.1 and have correctly created and registered my module, but I can't seem to detect the shipping methods. Basically, I want to hide **Cash on Delivery** if *Flat Rate* or *Free Shipping* is chosen. Here is the code I have for my observer class:

```
class Kol_PaymentToggle_Model_Observer
{
    public function paymentMethodIsActive(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event  = $observer->getEvent();
        $method = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result = $event->getResult(); 
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $shippingMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
        if($shippingMethod == "standardshipping" || $shippingMethod == "free") {
            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ) {
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that I haven't used the correct shipping method code names or payment method code names, but I'm unsure. Anyone has any advice?

**EDIT:**
I only have 3 shipping methods enabled:

- **Collect In Store** 
  Title = Collect in Store 
  Method Name = Collect In Store ([Extension link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/collect-in-store-checkout-shipping-option.html))
- **Flat Rate** 
  Title = Standard Delivery 
  Method Name = Standard Shipping
- **Free Shipping** 
  Title = Free Delivery 
  Method Name = Free

Hopefully this extra information can prove useful towards helping me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got an answer to [this same question on StackOverflow by user *Elvarasan*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604267/magento-onepage-checkout-hide-payment-method-depending-on-shipping-method). His answer provided me with everything I needed to get this working.

> To hide some payment methods based on shipping method you don't need to observe things at all:
>
> Every methods(in one page check out) post the methods which are chosen to the next level. So you can get the shipping method which are chosen, in payment method level. Just print the post things in
>
> ```
> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
> ```
>
> in this add below one,
>
> ```
> <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
> ```
>
> So now you can get the shipping methods which are chosen previous step. And note it, so now, you can add just simple logic (if else) condition in same file for hiding payment.
>
> For example here I want hide `check / money order` payment method, if shipping method is `flat`. Here the payment method code is `checkmo`. you can get payment method code by simply printing that variable like `echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();` in same file. so here just add simple if else ,
>
> ```
> <?php
>     $methods = $this->getMethods();
>     $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
> ?>
> <?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
>     <dt>
>         <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
>     </dt>
> <?php else:
>     foreach ($methods as $_method):
>        echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();
>
>
> if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
>     if($_code == 'checkmo') {
>         continue;
>     }
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> Here,
>
> ```
> if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
>     if($_code == 'checkmo') {
>         continue;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> checks the shipping method and skip the payment method which we don't want to display. That's it. Please comment here if you have any doubt.
>
> **Note:**
>
> ```
>  shipping_method => flatrate_flatrate
>  payment_method   => checkmo
> ```

Comment: If i have Owebia Shipping for shipping methods and IWD One Page Checkout, is it the right method to apply?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above method also worked for me, but my file location was different. 
/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/onestepcheckout/material/onestepcheckout/payment_method.phtml