# OnePage Checkout - Hide Payment method depending on selected shipping method

Tags: event-observer, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, payment-methods, dependency

I have a problem that is driving me nuts.
What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

During checkout I want to have different payment methods available depending on which shipping method was chosen.

I know there was already the same question before, but the answerrsprovided there didn't do he job. I tell you why:
I have done exactly what is suggested in the answer of [OnePage Checkout - Hide Payment method depending on Shipping Method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41075/onepage-checkout-hide-payment-method-depending-on-shipping-method)

What I have done is to create an Observer on the payment_method_is_active event:

```
class MyNameSpace_PaymentMethodFilter_Model_Observer{

public function paymentMethodIsActive(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $method = $event->getMethodInstance();

    $result = $event->getResult();
    $carriers = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
    if($carriers == 'flatrate_flatrate' ){
                if($method->getCode() == 'checkmo'){
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                }else{
                    $result->isAvailable = false;
                }
        }

}
}
```

The Problem with this observer is, that the payment_method_is_active event is only dispatched when the onepage is loaded the first time. This means, that after saving the shipping method, the observer doesn't receive any event and therefore can not apply the changes to the payment methods.

The availability of payment methods would rather need to be set when `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` is fired. But if I write an Observer for this event I don't know how I can access the current payment method instances to modify availability accordingly.

Can anyone show me how to solve my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604267/magento-onepage-checkout-hide-payment-method-depending-on-shipping-method

Comment: the above link gave  by @Sukeshini will work.....

Comment: dis you find a solution to this? please share it

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem (removing dynamically payment methods) and solved it by extending the `_canUseMethod($method)` function in `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods`.
There you can return false for specific payment methods which should not be shown in the payment selection.

Example:

```
class Company_Module_Block_Methods extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods {
    protected function _canUseMethod($method) {
        if ($method != null && $method == 'checkmo') {
            $carriers = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
            if ($carriers == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
                return parent::_canUseMethod($method);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return parent::_canUseMethod($method);
    }
}
```

The config XML would look like:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_payment_methods>Company_Module_Block_Methods</onepage_payment_methods>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

That way I could remove payment methods right before they get shown in the one page checkout.

Hope that helps anyone.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for us. We are integrating a new payment method that does not flow through the normal checkout, however the payment method was still available as a payment option during normal checkout. This solved the issue for us. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @7ok3n. I have this issue http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/magento-2-how-to-show-hide-payment-method-on-basis-of-amount so how to achieve this using `events.xml` instead of Plugin Can? What will be `<event name="controller_action_predispatch_XXX_XXX_XX">`?

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` provides a method `isAvailable` which returns a boolean value defining if this payment method is available for the current quote. Payment methods that extends this class can add their own logic that defines if it can be used or not. e.g `Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard`.

If you only want to do this to a single payment method as your SO question suggests, e.g `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery`. You could try extending it and creating your own is available function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It didn't answer my question but I already found a way to deal with the issue

Comment: Please elaborate on what approach you used instead